# Django - add a Integerfield in the template to every m2m object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add functionality to add a IntegerField next to every 'stockItem' in the template so that the user can type how many of that item was needed and then update the 'count' value in the 'Stock' model. As for now it only works when the user only selects one item. (I know that how I implement this now would never work but I try to show how I intend it to work)

Models:

```
class Machine_Service(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
stockItem = models.ManyToManyField(Stock)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
comment = models.TextField()
machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Stock(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
count = models.IntegerField(default=10)
minLimit = models.IntegerField(default=1)
resellerCompany = models.CharField(max_length=100)
resellerPerson = models.CharField(max_length=100)
resellerEmail = models.EmailField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

(I left the 'Machine' model out of this because it does not belong to the question)

view:

```
def CreateService(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateServiceForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        m = Machine.objects.get(id=form['machine'].value())
        service = Machine_Service(title=form['title'].value(), date=form['date'].value(), comment=form['comment'].value(), machine=m)
        service.save()
        items = form['stockItem'].value()
        for item in items:
            s = Stock.objects.get(id=item)
            service.stockItem.add(s)

        service.save()

        return redirect('Machines-Home')
else:
    form = CreateServiceForm()

context = {
'form': form
}
```

form:

```
class CreateServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
count = forms.IntegerField(required=False)    
class Meta:
    model = Machine_Service
    fields = ['title', 'stockItem', 'count', 'date', 'comment', 'machine']
```

template:
(I do not need to use crispy)

```
{% extends "maskinNytt/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Post!</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, is [this related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) to what you are trying to do? That you need to associate data with the relationship between the stock and the machine_service?

Comment: @bob Yes, I have been in there and reading. But I cant get my head around how to implement this in the forms.py or in my views.py/template. The thought is when the user creates a Machine_Service (you can look at that as an post/report) the user can specify if there were any Stock item needed and how many of those. Hope I am making myself clear now! -Thanks

Comment: @AndreasYpper I am pretty much struggling with same issue as you had in the past, did you find a solution that fitted your needs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case your models.py should look something like this:

```
class Machine_Service(models.Model):
    stockItem = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, through='NeededItems')
    ...

class Stock(models.Model):
    ...

class NeededItem(models.Model):
    machine_service = models.ForeignKey(Machine_Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

To specify this amount and use it in your views/forms you need to just create instances of `NeededItem`.

I assume you have a form for the MachineService and one for a NeededItem. For the NeededItems you need a FormSet, views.py:

```
from django import formset_factory
NeededItemFormset = formset_factory(NeededItemForm, extra=2)

def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        machine_form = MachineForm(request.POST, prefix='machine')
        needed_item_formset = NeededItemFormset(request.POST, prefix='items')
        if machine_form.is_valid() and needed_item_formset.is_valid():
            machine_form.save()
            needed_item_formset.save()
            return redirect('blabla')
    else:
        machine_form = MachineForm()
        needed_item_formset = NeededItemFormset()
    return render('template', {'m_form': machine_form, 'n_form': needed_item_formset})
```

The template then might look something like this.

```
<form>
  {% machine_service_form.as_p %}
  {% needed_item_formset.as_p %}
</form>
```

(I didn't test this, so I don't give guarantees it works, but I think you should have enough pointers to figure out which things you need).

When one would make a `Machine_Service` they would also need a form (or multiple) for the `NeededItem` model. That means you can basically ignore the `Stock` model when creating `Machine_Service`s.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I do get that part. The problem I have is to understand how my view and template should look like. Let's say i want to have a lable for the stockItem.title and then have the amount field after each object.

Comment: See my edited answer, to have that you need to add a formset to save multiple items and you need to add prefix when instantiating the forms to make it possible for Django to have multiple forms on a page.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it does not quite solve the problem. But you have given me the tools and pointers to solve it for my self. So I accepted your answer. I will post how my code turned out later!

Comment: It's my pleasure to help!